# Inconclusive Error Message with download.file

Tags: r, download

I tried to download several thousand SEC files via the command:

```
download.file(link, folder, method = "internal", quiet = FALSE, 
              mode = "wb", cacheOK = TRUE,
              extra = getOption("download.file.extra"))
```

After a while I get the following message that I cannot interpret:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4149177/Capture.PNG

It seems that the files are downloaded successfully, however I want to know what the message means.

Can you tell me what R tries to tell me?

Full code:

```
setInternet2(use = FALSE)
destinationfolder <- getwd()
startyear <- 2000
stopyear <- 2000
startquarter <- 1
stopquarter <- 2
filetype <- "10-Q"

func.getsecindexfile<- function(year, quarter) {

    #### download the zipped index file from the SEC website

    tf <- tempfile()

    result <- try(download.file(url=paste("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/", year,"/QTR", quarter, "/company.zip",sep=""), destfile=tf))

    #### if we didn't encounter and error downloading the file, parse it and return as a R data frame

    if (!inherits(result, "try-error")) {

        #### small function to remove leading and trailing spaces

        trim <- function (string) {

            string <- enc2native(string)      
            gsub("^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$","\\1", string, perl=TRUE)

        }

        #### read the downloaded file

        raw.data <- readLines(con=(zz<- unz(description=tf, filename="company.idx")))

        close(zz)

        #### remove the first 10 rows

        raw.data <- raw.data[11:length(raw.data)] 

        #### parse the downloaded file and return the extracted data as a data frame

        company_name <- trim(substr(raw.data,1,62))

        form_type <- trim(substr(raw.data,63,74))

        cik <- trim(substr(raw.data,75,86))

        date_filed <- as.Date(substr(raw.data,87,98))

        file_name <- trim(substr(raw.data,99,150))

        rm(raw.data)

        return(data.frame(company_name, form_type, cik, date_filed, file_name))

    } 

    else {return(NULL)} 

}

#### add index files to database

func.addindexfiletodatabase <- function(data){

    if (is.null(data)) return(NULL)

    rs <- dbWriteTable(sqlite,  "filings", data, append=TRUE)

    return(rs)

}  

dbGetQuery(sqlite, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS filings")

for (year in startyear:stopyear){

    for (quarter in startquarter:stopquarter){

        func.addindexfiletodatabase(func.getsecindexfile(year, quarter))

    }
}

selection <- paste("SELECT * FROM filings WHERE form_type IN ('", filetype, "')", sep = "")

index <- dbGetQuery(sqlite, selection)

pre <- c("ftp://ftp.sec.gov/")

index <- cbind(index,pre)
temp <- paste(index$pre, index$file_name, sep = "")
index <- cbind(index,temp)
index$name_new <- index$temp

index$name_new <- gsub("ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/","",index$name_new)

index$name_new <- gsub("/","-",index$name_new)

name <- paste(index$name_new)
link <- paste(index$temp, sep = "")

index$pre <- NULL
index$temp <- NULL

#### define download function

func.download_files <- function(link,name) {

    folder <- paste(destinationfolder, "\\", name, sep="")  

    download.file(link, folder, method="internal", quiet = FALSE, mode = "wb", cacheOK = TRUE, extra = getOption("download.file.extra"))
}


#### download the files

mapply(FUN = func.download_files,link=link,name=name)
```

Comment: Could you post the full code, are you running this in the loop?

Comment: Indeed it is a loop over a column of ftp paths.

Comment: On principle, you would encapsulate any desired printable output in a *print* statement if deciding to show the command results from within the loop. Are you getting this after the loop or while it's running. Try to amend your post so it's reproducible.

Comment: I have edited my post. Actually I don't have included a print command.

Answer (score 0):

The "error" was a notification that the files was successfully downloaded. Thank your for your help.